# sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: c++, linux, bash, ffmpeg

Hi iam using following c++ code to create ffmpeg command. When i run this command in bash using linux popen, following error occurs. If i put the command directly in bash, it works fine and doesn't give any other. Please help me figure out the cause of it.

C++ code to generate command:

```
 const string VideoCreator::GetFFMPEG_Silent_Audio_Merge_command()
{ 
    stringstream command;
    command << FFMPEG_BINARY  << " -nostdin -loglevel error -y -threads 0 -f concat -safe 0 -i <(echo file /home/ec2-user/videoData/DnXptC4ld8/FADING_OUT_VOLUP_Blrt_Decrypt_1ed5c4d569d8a1f23428b65217f65eaf_audio.m4a; echo file /home/ec2-user/videocreation/temp/silence.m4a) -c copy " << _outputAudioWithSilence;// << " 2> " << _ffmpeg_log_file;
    std::cout << "\n Command = " << command.str() << "\n";
    return command.str();
}
```

Bash error:

```
 sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
 sh: -c: line 0: `/opt/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel error -y -threads 0 -f concat -safe 0 -i <(echo file /home/ec2-user/videoData/DnXptC4ld8/FADING_OUT_VOLUP_Blrt_Decrypt_1ed5c4d569d8a1f23428b65217f65eaf_audio.m4a; echo file /home/ec2-user/videocreation/temp/silence.m4a) -c copy /home/ec2-user/videoData/DnXptC4ld8/WITH_SILENCE_FADING_OUT_VOLUP_Blrt_Decrypt_1ed5c4d569d8a1f23428b65217f65eaf_audio.m4a'
```

Comment: The command is executed by `/bin/sh` (not `bash`), which does not support process substitution.

Comment: so how to run this command with popen then?

Comment: For this case, see if you can work with `command << "(echo file /home/ec2-user/videoData/DnXptC4ld8/FADING_OUT_VOLUP_Blrt_Decrypt_1ed5c4d569d8a1f23428b65217f65eaf_audio.m4a; echo file /home/ec2-user/videocreation/temp/silence.m4a) | "<< FFMPEG_BINARY  << " -loglevel error -y -threads 0 -f concat -safe 0 -i /dev/stdin -c copy " << _outputAudioWithSilence`